# Insert data into tables that matches the login username

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an account and diklat table, how do I want to insert data into diklat table that matches the login username?

> **Tabel Akun**

[image]

> **Tabel diklat**

[image]

> **Controller diklat**

```
public function tambah()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_namadiklat', 'nama_diklat', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Nama Diklat Belum Diisi!']);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_penyelenggara', 'penyelenggara', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Penyelenggara Diklat Harus Diisi!']);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_tempatdiklat', 'tempat_diklat', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Tempat Diklat Harus Diisi!']);

        $data['title'] = ' Tambah Diklat';
        $data['akun'] = $this->db->get_where('akun', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/top_bar');
            $this->load->view('templates/sidebarmenu');
            $this->load->view('diklat/tambah');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }else
        {
            if ($data)
            {
                $array = [
                    'nama_diklat'   => $this->input->post('f_namadiklat'),
                    'jenis_diklat'  => $this->input->post('f_jenisdiklat'),
                    'penyelenggara' => $this->input->post('f_penyelenggara'),
                    'tempat_diklat' => $this->input->post('f_tempatdiklat'),
                    'waktu_diklat'  => $this->input->post('tgl_diklat'),
                ];

                //insert to database
                $this->db->insert('diklat', $array);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                Data Berhasil ditambah</div>');
                redirect('diklat/index');
            }else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                Data Gagal Disimpan</div>');
                redirect('diklat/tambah');
            }
        }
    }
```

> **function get all data from tabel diklat join akun**
> when table diklat has been added successfully, data on a different id_akun also appears.

```
function view_diklat()
{
    $query =    "SELECT * FROM diklat JOIN akun ON diklat.id_akun = akun.id";

    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
}
```

> **controller function index diklat**

```
public function index()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Pelatihan & Seminar';
    $data['akun'] = $this->db->get_where('akun', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();

    $data['data'] = $this->diklat_m->view_diklat();

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/sidebarmenu');
    $this->load->view('templates/top_bar');
    $this->load->view('diklat/index');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

Comment: Controllers should not be performing database reads or manipulations -- that is the job of model methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in variable $array field id_akun not declared to store in diklat table

so in $array change to

```
$array = [
    'id_akun'   => $data['akun']['id'],
    'nama_diklat'   => $this->input->post('f_namadiklat'),
    'jenis_diklat'  => $this->input->post('f_jenisdiklat'),
    'penyelenggara' => $this->input->post('f_penyelenggara'),
    'tempat_diklat' => $this->input->post('f_tempatdiklat'),
    'waktu_diklat'  => $this->input->post('tgl_diklat'),
```

];

or

```
$array = [
     'id_akun'   => $data['akun']->id,
     'nama_diklat'   => $this->input->post('f_namadiklat'),
     'jenis_diklat'  => $this->input->post('f_jenisdiklat'),
     'penyelenggara' => $this->input->post('f_penyelenggara'),
     'tempat_diklat' => $this->input->post('f_tempatdiklat'),
     'waktu_diklat'  => $this->input->post('tgl_diklat'),
```

];

for get the name of user in view_diklat

```
 function view_diklat()
{
    $email = $this->session->userdata('email'); 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM diklat JOIN akun ON diklat.id_akun = akun.id where akun.email = '$email' ";
    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
}
```

Comment: thanks, now the id_akun has been successfully added to table diklat. but in selecting data, how do I display the data according to the account id

Comment: join the diklat table with akun table and get the nama of user

Comment: like this? $query = "SELECT `diklat`.*  FROM `diklat` JOIN `akun` ON `diklat`.`id_akun` = `akun`.`id`";

Comment: like this, $query = "SELECT * FROM diklat JOIN akun ON diklat.id_akun = akun.id"; use * to get all fields of all table

Comment: but in the diklat table view, data with a different id_akun also appears

Comment: if you only want to display one record,you can add condition where in query, example diklat.id_akun = $user_id,

Comment: can you explain, what kind of result do you want?

Comment: i want to display data diklat based on the id_akun that is currently logged in

Comment: in view_diklat try this, $query =    "SELECT * FROM diklat JOIN akun ON diklat.id_akun = akun.id where akun.email = ".$this->session->userdata('email');

Comment: I have an error in SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1

Comment: try this way, $email = $this->session->userdata('email'); $query = "SELECT * FROM diklat JOIN akun ON diklat.id_akun = akun.id where akun.email = '$email' ";

Comment: A model method should never be directly accessing the session object.  Data should be passed into model methods so that they can be flexible enough to be reused in the project.  Model methods should be designed to be ignorant of their data sources.

Comment: So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function tambah() {
```

// Get the logged-in user's email from session data
$user_email = $this->session->userdata('email');

```
// Query the 'akun' table to get the user's data
$user = $this->db->get_where('akun', ['email' => $user_email])->row_array();

// Check if the user's data was found
if ($user) {
    // Set up validation rules for the form fields
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_namadiklat', 'nama_diklat', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Nama Diklat Belum Diisi!']);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_penyelenggara', 'penyelenggara', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Penyelenggara Diklat Harus Diisi!']);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_tempatdiklat', 'tempat_diklat', 'required|trim', ['required' => 'Tempat Diklat Harus Diisi!']);

    $data['title'] = ' Tambah Diklat';
    $data['akun'] = $user;

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        // Load the form view with validation errors
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/top_bar');
        $this->load->view('templates/sidebarmenu');
        $this->load->view('diklat/tambah');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    } else {
        // Create an array with the form input data and the user's email
        $array = [
            'nama_diklat'   => $this->input->post('f_namadiklat'),
            'jenis_diklat'  => $this->input->post('f_jenisdiklat'),
            'penyelenggara' => $this->input->post('f_penyelenggara'),
            'tempat_diklat' => $this->input->post('f_tempatdiklat'),
            'waktu_diklat'  => $this->input->post('tgl_diklat'),
            'email'         => $user_email,
        ];

        // Insert the data into the 'diklat' table
        $this->db->insert('diklat', $array);

        // Set a success message in the session and redirect to the 'index' page
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Data Berhasil ditambah</div>');
        redirect('diklat/index');
    }
} else {
    // If the user's data was not found, set an error message in the session and redirect to the 'login' page
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">User tidak ditemukan</div>');
    redirect('auth/login');
}
```

}
``

Comment: Thank you, but when i click button Tambah, got an error "The page you requested was not found" and redirect(auth/login);

Comment: this code button Tambah <a href="<?= base_url('diklat/tambah'); ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-success float-right">Tambah Data</a>